# Как правильно реализовать поиск по RecyclerView?

Tags: android

Подскажите как лучше реализовать поиск по RecyclerView
В моей БД (и соответственно в RecyclerView) около 300 строк. Запрос поиска в реальном времени слушается в EditText. И я вижу 2 варианта:

1. Recycler заполнить напрямую из БД через Cursor, при каждом изменении символа в EditText создавать новый Cursor ( делать поиск запросом в SQL ) и отдавать адаптеру, обновлять данные в адаптере. Т.е поиск средствами самой БД.
2. Сделать массив объектов (ArrayList) из БД, заполнить им Recycler и реализовывать самому поиск в массиве по полю объекта, обновляя данные массива для поиска, и отдавать в адаптер.

Как будет правильнее и оптимальнее с точки зрения скорости работы?

Comment: Тут нельзя правильно сделать. Можно лишь сделать так, как вам надо. Если в процессе поиска данные в БД могут поменяться - то ищите через БД. Если не могут - можно и так и эдак. Какой способ быстрее будет во втором случае? Ну, надо замерять. Скорее всего поиск не в БД будет в этом случае быстрее.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так я реализовал подобное у себя. Функция filter() содержит логику поиска и показа результатов. Вызов этой функции нужно делать в функции afterTextChanged в TextWatcher, который нужно привязать к поисковому полю. В коде есть корутины, чтобы избежать лагов в приложении. Код без корутин и специфичных функций приложу ниже оригинального.

```
//функция принимает на вход поисковой запрос
fun filter(text: String) {
    //пустой список, в котором будут находится элементы, удовлетворяющие запросу
    val filteredList = mutableListOf<Notes>()

    launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        // mainList - переменная, содержащая все данные из БД
        mainList = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { mainViewModel.getData() }

        // тут цикл берет каждый элемент списка, превращает весь текст в текст нижнего регистра, что поиск работал корректно, а потом проверяет, содержит ли текущий элемент поисковой запрос и если да, то он добавляется в новый специальный список
        for (item in mainList) {
            item.text?.let {
                if (it.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).contains(text.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT))) {
                    filteredList.add(item)
                }
            }
        }

        // тут я главный список делаю равным поисковому, т.к. он мне нужен для обеспечения такой же кликабельности элементов в активити для других задач, в противном случае этот список будет просто декорацией(в моем случае недопустимо)
        mainList = filteredList
        // здесь результат поиска присваиваем к главному адаптеру(в адаптере должна быть соответствующая функция setList())
        notesAdapter.setList(filteredList)
    }
}
```

Код без корутин и let:

```
fun filter(text: String) {
    val filteredList = mutableListOf<Notes>()

    for (item in mainList) {
        if (item.text.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).contains(text.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT))) {
            filteredList.add(item)
        }
    }

    mainList = filteredList
    notesAdapter.setList(filteredList)
}
```